# Repeating an included template with different data?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to reuse a simple template with different objects. The template is inserted with `ng-include` attributes, and the objects are assigned from the template with `ng-init`.

This used to work, but after upgrading to Angular 1.2.8, the second object instance seems to overwrite the first and I end up with two identical instances -- or more precisely, two representations of the same object.

Here's a simplified example:

```html
<h3>Dogs</h3>
<div ng-init="items = dogs" ng-include="'tile.html'">dogs</div>

<h3>Cats</h3>
<div ng-init="items = cats" ng-include="'tile.html'">cats</div>
```

The `tile.html` template is simply:

```html
  <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="i in items">{{ i }}</li>
  </ul>
```

The Angular controller simply provides `$scope` variables:

```js
$scope.dogs = ['Beagle', 'Chihuahua', 'Poodle'];
$scope.cats = ['Abyssinian', 'Bengal', 'Tabby'];
```

The desired behavior is two distinct lists, one of dogs, the other of cats. Instead, it now renders two lists of cats.

Plunkr example: http://plnkr.co/edit/st7pqF?p=preview

Is there a better way of passing different data to multiple template instances?

#### Additional findings

Using the Plunkr, I was able to quickly step through dozens of Angular releases. It's possible this only ever worked because of a bug.

Every Angular release from 1.0.2 - 1.1.5 shows the second list twice. Angular 1.2.0 - 1.2.3 display two different lists. Versions 1.2.4 - 1.2.8 have reverted back to duplicating the second list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a directive. It is intimidating at first, but once you get used to it, it becomes quite obvious.

The directive (dead simple):

```
app.directive("rep", function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      items: "="
    },
    templateUrl: "tile.html"
  };
});
```

The HTML:

```
<div rep="" items="cats"></div>
```

And the forked plunk (Angular 1.2.7): http://plnkr.co/edit/402qVL1Z5By1agG1N8Lh?p=preview

---

For completeness: I do not like `ng-init`. It is kind of procedural logic in the HTML. That is why I am actually bypassing your problem with a cleaner (IMHO) solution.

Comment: That's what I was thinking. Reading over the Angular Directive docs again, my question was pretty much the first example... Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: any particular reason for using `rep=""` instead of just `rep`?

Comment: Ha, just to please the code formatter :)  The interesting thing would be to include the repetition expression in the same attribute that defines the template, i.e. `rep="cats"` instead of `rep items="cats"`.

Comment: That was the first thing I tried, it works perfectly: `<div items="cats"></div>` Now I'm just trying to shoehorn this around my actual problem, which is recursive and uncooperative.

Comment: Full API docs for Angular directives are buried in [ng.$compile](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$compile) Wish I'd found that sooner.