# not getting the different controllers

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

Hello I have one HTML template name as a.html as below

```
<div ng-controller="a"></div>
```

in js file

```
app.controller('a',[$scope, function($scope)]){
// here i make some array and this array is populated on view 
}]);
```

Now I include a.html to another file as b.html using ng-include-src='path of the a.html'.
Here it i want to display the same view (a.html view )12 times in b.html file. With different values each time.

Can any one suggest me the solution? 
I have tried the

```
$rootScope.$emit('TEST')
```

and captured it in a (a controller) assign different values. But When b.html is view is loaded at that each 12 instances of (a.html) giving me different scopes.

Sorry i didn't get time to put on jsfiddle.

Comment: Use a directive, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21096107) related question.

Comment: Hello @NikosParaskevopoulos I have used the same example which you have given in plunkr. I this case i am not able to get array. In your example you have assigned the array as dogs.

Comment: hello @NikosParaskevopoulos my code in html is below
<div class="panel" ng-controller="Controller" >
 <div rep="" myArray="arr" dayArray="dayName">
</div></div>

in the controller i have both the arrays. in directive  i have written 
app.directive("rep", function() {
 console.log("in rep directive");
   return {
     scope: {
       myArr: "=",
       dayArray : "="
     },
     templateUrl: "public/views/myHtml.html"
   };
 });

Comment: can you please suggest

Comment: hello @NikosParaskevopoulos i have tried an alert it first goes in directive and then in controller. Can any one please suggest where i am doing wrong